# Using generics to enforce valid structure at compile time

Tags: c#, generics, types

By abusing the type system in c#, I can create code, where the compiler will enforce a rule, to ensure an impossible operation is not performed. In the below code, its specific to matrix multiplication.

Obviously the below is totally impractical/wrong, but are there reasons we cant have something like this in c# in the future, where I could define a type like Matrix<2,2> and have the compiler ensure safety?

Also, does anything like this exist in any mainstream languages? I'd suspect something like this might be possible with metaprogramming in C++??

```
public abstract class MatrixDimension { }

public class One : MatrixDimension { }
public class Two : MatrixDimension { }
public class Three : MatrixDimension { }

public class Matrix<TRow, TCol>
    where TRow : MatrixDimension
    where TCol : MatrixDimension
{

// matrix mult. rule. N×M * M×P  = N×P 
    public Matrix<TRow, T_RHSCol> Mult<T_RHSCol>(Matrix<TCol, T_RHSCol> rhs)
        where T_RHSCol : MatrixDimension
    { return null;}
}

public class TwoByTwo : Matrix<Two, Two> { }

public void Main()
{
    var twoByTwo = new Matrix<Two, Two>();
    var oneByTwo = new Matrix<One, Two>();
    var twoByThree = new Matrix<Two, Three>();
    var threeByTwo = new Matrix<Three, Two>();
    var _twoByTwo = new TwoByTwo();

    var _2x2 = twoByTwo.Mult(twoByTwo);
    var _1x2 = oneByTwo.Mult(twoByTwo);
    var _3x3 = twoByThree.Mult(threeByTwo);

    var _2x2_ = _twoByTwo.Mult(twoByTwo);

    var invalid = twoByThree.Mult(twoByThree); // compile fails, as expected
}
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me...what should and shouldn't be valid?

Comment: In matrix math, you can multiply two matrices,e.g. 2x3 * 3x4, and output a 2x4 matrix. Note the 3's. This 'parity' must be the case, otherwise its not possible mathematically. By doing what I've done with the types above, I can make the compiler ensure (at compile time), someone doesnt try to do a 2x2 * 3x3, which is impossible. With me?

Comment: Ah, yes, now I get it.  My first guess is that that's not possible in C# through any method that's significantly simpler than your example.  Matrix<2,2> just doesn't work.  Anything else happens at runtime.

Comment: should you be able to multiply 2x3 *2x3?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: No. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication for many details on how it works.

Comment: Im not actually sure what the question is, your example appears to do exactly what you are asking for

Comment: sure, but its not practical. who wants to define a new type for every number. having to do this, is abuse of the type system. Is there a language that allows me to do something similar, but supply numbers in place of the type (one = 1, two = 2), and have the compiler do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# has support for [units of measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) built into the language - basically creating a richer type system on top of the CLR types, like what you've started doing with generics.

A different, and I would argue complementary, approach to building a richer type system (which I'm using in my own software to ensure high reliability and correctness in the core modules) is to use the compiler in conjunction with a *theorem prover* to guarantee that pre- and post-conditions on methods and properties (as well as class invariants) are met.

This is well-known in mainstream languages like [SPARKAda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARK_%28programming_language%29) and [Java (via JML extensions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Modeling_Language) - and it's available for C# as well, thanks to Microsoft Research's work on the [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) feature.  (Which I'm making heavy use of.  I highly recommend watching the videos linked on the MSR page, they're the best way to get started with these tools.)

The *cccheck* static checker from MSR can run in the background of Visual Studio, and will give you error and informational messages along with (I think purple) squigglies in your code editor.

If you want to go down that route, check out the [Code Contracts MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/threads) for support - that's where most users seem to hang out.

Comment: I've used CC, and never thought of using it this way. Must see if I can abuse it too ;) The F# units of measure looks very interesting. Finally the excuse I need to check F# out.